# Is the order of an arraylist guaranteed in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

If I'm using an ArrayList in C#.NET, is the order guaranteed to stay the same as the order I add items to it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, elements are always added to the end (unless you specify otherwise, e.g. with a call to [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.insert.aspx)). In other words, if you do:

```
int size = list.Count;
int index = list.Add(element);
Assert.AreEqual(size, index); // Element is always added at the end
Assert.AreEqual(element, list[index]); // Returned index is position in list
```

The position will change if you remove any earlier elements or insert new elements ahead of it, of course.

Is there any good reason for you to use `ArrayList` rather than `List<T>` by the way? Non-generic collections are *so* 2003...

(The order is stable in `List<T>` as well, by the way.)

Comment: "Non-generic collections are so 2003..." - LOL, nice one Jon, that's going up as my quote of the week :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is, unless some piece of your code changes the order by e.g. swapping.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is. Since it's stored as an array.

Other properties are

- Guaranteed order
- Random access. You can access any element by index in O(1)
- Slow insert and delete in the beginning and middle.
- Unsorted. (Sorting should take O(n log n) using quicksort or similar)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [silly answer length limit]

Answer (score 0):

When you add an item to a ArrayList the item will always stay at that index. Unless of course if you change it.

(the framework might rearrange the memory but your index will always stay the same)